# From inside container, the hostname translates to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The goal here is I want to connect this backend(python) server to the mysql, but the problem is that the "mysql" hostname inside the docker container translates to 127.0.0.1 which is wrong, it should be an ip from the network like 192.168.x.x. I tried to add links and external_links to the docker compose file but it didn't help.
What did I do wrong here?

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  client:
    build: frontend
    image: project/client
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    networks:
      - frontend

  server:
    build: ./server
    image: project/server
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - project-server-vol:/data
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
    volumes:
      - project-mysql-vol:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

volumes:
 project-server-vol: {}
 project-mysql-vol: {}

networks:
  frontend: {}
  backend: {}
```

Comment: Inside which container does it resolve to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Please include the output from how you're verifying the mysql DNS resolution is wrong. A project like nicolaka/netshoot may help.

Comment: @HansKilian I am trying to resolve from the server container.

Comment: may you please provide the ```docker network inspect name``` of both networks (find names with ```docker network ls```) ?

Comment: When I try to replicate it, mysql resolves to 192.168.144.2 from inside the server container

Comment: @araisch Here is the 2 inspects: https://pastebin.com/DCmZsZr0

Comment: Try ```mysql: networks: backend: aliases: - mysql``` or ```hostname``` property. Or set ```container_name: mysql``` Anyways, ```docker inspect containerName``` property ```alias``` must contain the string mysql..

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql shouldn't resolve to 127.0.0.1, make sure your host machine's `/etc/hosts` file do not have any entry like `127.0.0.1    mysql`. Try the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
services:
  nginx1:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
    - frontend
  nginx2:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
  nginx3:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
    - backend

docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec nginx1 wget -qO- nginx2 #-- OK, notice you access using service name "nginx2"
docker-compose exec nginx2 wget -qO- nginx3 #-- OK, notice you access using service name "nginx3"
docker-compose exec nginx1 wget -qO- nginx3 #-- expected to fail as not on the same network.
docker-compose down
```

The above sample is proven to be working. Should all goes well on your machine, you can replace nginx1 with your frontend, nginx2 with your server and nginx3 with your mysql. It should prove that your mysql should not resolve to 127.0.0.1